# R package to CRAN: had CPU time 5 times elapsed time

Tags: r, r-package, cran

just providing my solution to the issue that occurs when submitting a package to CRAN and getting an error similar to this:

```r
* checking tests ... [838s/167s] NOTE
  Running ‘testthat.R’ [838s/167s]
Running R code in ‘testthat.R’ had CPU time 5 times elapsed time
```

Now I couldn't replicate this error (locally, on win-hub or rhub) and found very little information on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a few helpful discussions on the R-pkg-devel mailing list: The result of the R-core discussions [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2023q3/009513.html) or a question for another package that had the same issue [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-package-devel@r-project.org/msg08794.html) with the solution on GitHub [here](https://github.com/business-science/modeltime/blob/0b2a9156246a6bb6f22f0ea4e9937f0260106b9f/R/zzz.R#L16).

Essentially the issue is related to the number of CPU cores used by a package - and the CRAN policy to try to avoid a package using too many by default.

The solution involves setting the variable `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` to `2`. For this, I created a new file called `packagename.R` that looked like this:

```r
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  # CRAN OMP THREAD LIMIT
  Sys.setenv("OMP_THREAD_LIMIT" = 2)

}
```

And this did the trick when submitting it to CRAN next time around. Hopefully this is useful to others as well!